# Validating credit card expiry date against todays date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working on an assignment for school where we're working with JavaScript (I'm only allowed to use JavaScript) to validate a form for a payment page. It's my first time working with JavaScript so and I feel a bit lost...

I'm faced with a task to validate the expiry date and the requirements are:

1. the number needs to be exactly 2-2 digits (in the format mm-yy)
2. mm needs to be >01 and <12
3. and the expiry date needs to be after today's date

So far I've only been able to specify the first two requirements and I have trouble figuring out how to check the date against today's date.

html

```
<form>
<label for="expiryDate">Expiry Date</label>
<input type="text" name="expiryDate" id="expiryDate" />

<input type="submit" value="Check out" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var expiryDate = document.getElementById("expiryDate").value;

if (!expiryDate.match(/^[0][1-9]|[1][0-2]-[0-9]{2}$/)){
    errMsg = errMsg + "The expiry date needs to be mm-yy and consist of a valid date.\n";
    result = false;
}
```

So if anyone has an idea of how to help me, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Note that your regex will match values like `"99-12"`. Anyway, as far as getting the current date's month and year, have you looked at methods of the `Date` object like [`.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) and `.getFullYear()`?

Comment: I don't know why some insist on two digit months, 1-18 should be perfectly valid. Why force users to add a leading zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help

```
var today = new Date(); // gets the current date
var today_mm = today.getMonth() + 1; // extracts the month portion
var today_yy = today.getFullYear() % 100; // extracts the year portion and changes it from yyyy to yy format

if(today_mm < 10) { // if today's month is less than 10
    today_mm = '0' + today_mm // prefix it with a '0' to make it 2 digits
} 

var mm = expiryDate.substring(0, 2); // get the mm portion of the expiryDate (first two characters)
var yy = expiryDate.substring(3); // get the yy portion of the expiryDate (from index 3 to end)

if (yy > today_yy || (yy == today_yy && mm >= today_mm)) {
   // all good because the yy from expiryDate is greater than the current yy
   // or if the yy from expiryDate is the same as the current yy but the mm
   // from expiryDate is greater than the current mm
}
else
{
   errMsg = errMsg + "The expiry date needs to be greater than today.\n";
   result = false;
}
```

Comment: you could also concatenate each yymm ... then just check if yymm >= today_yymm :p

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm still not getting it completely... 

It's probably the easiest thing ever (but I've never done any programming of anything before so I have no clue...), but I can't figure out where in the code to put that? 

Should it be placed by itself as a new statement.. Or should it be placed inside this
"if (!expiryDate.match(/^[0-9]{2}-[0][1-9]|[1][0-2]$/)){
    errMsg = errMsg + "The expiry date needs to be mm-yy and consist of a valid date.\n";
    result = false;
}" 
somehow?

Comment: @SaraBjörkqvist As you said you've already implemented checks for the first two requirements, my answer was just solving the third check. So you'd place it after your existing javascript code.

Comment: @SaraBjörkqvist I will edit my answer to include additional comments to explain what's happening

Answer (score 1):

I'm always surprised at how programmers would rather spend their efforts building straight-jackets for users rather than writing user friendly code.

The month criteria seem to be incorrect, ">01 and <12" infers a value from 2 to 11 inclusive, I expect that ">=1 and <=12" was intended.

To do exactly what the assignment requires, you could do something like:

```js
/* Check that the provided string is:
**  - exactly 2-2 digits in the format mm-yy
**  - mm is >= 01 and <= 12
**  - expiry date is this month or later
*/
function validateExpiryDate(s) {

  // Check 2-2 digits
  if (!/\d\d-\d\d/.test(s)) {
    return 'Expiry date format must be MM-YY: ' + s;
  }
  
  // Check month is 1 to 12 inclusive
  var b = s.split('-');
  if (b[0]<1 || b[0]>12) {
    return 'Expiry month must be from 00 to 12: ' + b[0];
  }
  
  // Check is this month or later
  var d = new Date()
  var c = d.getFullYear()/100 | 0 + '';
  if (new Date(c + b[1], b[0], 1) < d) {
    return 'Expiry date must be this month or later: ' + s;
  }
  
  return true;
}

// Some tests
['01-17','12-17','foo','13-20','9-18'].forEach(function(s){
  console.log(validateExpiryDate(s));
})
```

However, to be a little more user friendly, you can accept single digits and various separators quite easily. Also, you can just cut to the chase and test whether the value entered generates a suitable expiry date. You can also reformat the entered string into the required format, e.g.:

```js
// Validate expiry date in m-yy format
// Separator can be any non-digit
function checkExpiryDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date();
  var century = d.getFullYear()/100 | 0;
  // Generate date for first day of following month
  var expires = new Date(century + b[1], b[0], 1);
  return d < expires;
}

// Reformat date in m/yy format to mm-yy strict
function formatExpiry(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + +n}
  return z(b[0]) + '-' + z(b[1]);
}

['1/1','4-17','03-17','3-18','06/19','3.19','foo'].forEach(function(s) {
  console.log('String "' + s + '" converts to "' + 
               formatExpiry(s) + '" and is ' + 
               (checkExpiryDate(s)? '' : 'not ') + 'valid.');
});
```

So being user friendly is also less code to write. ;-)

Calculating the century is a bit of overkill, you could just use "20" and expect that your code will not be running in 2095 when expiry dates will start having centuries of "21".